# Can Solana Programs send network requests?

Tags: solana-program

I know that users can send data to Solana Programs and retrieve data from Solana Programs. I am curious if we are able to make network calls inside Solana Programs. Assume a user interacted with program and sent a required data to call an API. Let's say user sent string "California". Can we make a network call to a weather API and return weather data?

Comment: By the way I'm aware weather example is irrelevant and there is no point of doing that. It is just an example to solidify what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  It is impossible to do IO tasks like network requests deterministically.  There are many ways that the behavior of the request could change from one validator to another